# How can I detect when the Flyout for a given DatePicker opens in WinUI 3?

Tags: datepicker, popup, winui-3, flyout, visual-tree

I have a `DatePicker` on a `Page` and would like to know whenever the `DatePickerFlyout` associated with the `DatePicker` is opened. This would be straightforward if I had a reference to the relevant `DatePickerFlyout` (`DatePickerFlyout` has `Opened` and `Opening` events) , but I can't seem to find one.

`Flyout`s (`Popup`s) appear in the `Visual Tree` under `PopupRoot` so I thought I might listen for changes in the `PopupRoot` branch. But walking up the tree stops at the `RootScrollViewer`, one level below `PopupRoot`, so I can't reference that branch.

`VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot()` returns a list of open `Popup`s (which includes `Flyout`s) but only if the `Flyout` in question is actually open.

Any idea how I can find and work with the actual `DatePickerFlyout` object?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried but couldn't succeed. The closest thing might be just using the ``Tapped`` event of the ``DatePicker`` control.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewKeepCoding. I did figure out an extremely tortured way to determine when the `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter` is added to the `VisualTree`, but nothing for the `DataPickerFlyout`. It seems strange to me but `Flyout`s (and `Popup`s in general) don't seem to be connected in any way to the `UIElement`s that invoke them.

Comment: If you really need to work with the flyout, you could just create a custom control, implement it based on the actual ``DatePicker`` and show a ``Flyout`` based on the ``DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`` style.

Comment: I've tried that but some of the characteristics must be set in code and override anything set in XAML (for example, the placeholder text of "month", "day", and "year") and I can't find the source for the `DatePicker` to look at what's going on. Overriding `OnApplyTemplate` doesn't help, either. Any idea where I can find the source? And thanks again for the help!

Comment: I mean, you can implement a ``DatePicker`` control yourself but using the styles from the actual ``DatePicker`` to have the same look. It's just a button with a flyout for date selection after all.

Comment: I see what you mean. How silly of me. Excellent point - thanks.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't clear enough.